Plugin/Integration with Bitbucket or Jira to notify user when PRs are made affecting a specific subdirectory
Pretty much as title states. I am looking for any suggestions that you guys may have used where the plugin/integration can notify user(s) if any PR has been opened that changes a specific subdirectory or anything under that subdirectory.
For example:
If a PR is opened that changes a file in repo/main/NOTIFYME/..., then it will send a notification, email, or some kind of alert to the user.
This should trigger even if there are multiple subdirectories under ../NOTIFYME/randomDirectory.
Any suggestions is appreciated. It can be a paid plugin/integration for Jira/Bitbucket.
